# Show/hide div when you use mouse click on another div

Tags: css, html

Is it possible to show/hide div when user click somewhere else? For example i have two divs:

```
<div>Title</div>
<div>description</div>
```

Description is initaially hidden, but when user click on Title div, description div should appear.

is it possible w/o java script?

EDIT: mouse click show show description div. to hide this div, user should click title div again.

Comment: events like that need to be captured with javascript, if you could change your markup you could show the description when hovering over the title, but this would require them being wrapped in a parent div

Comment: Do you expect the description to stay up until the title is clicked again, or just have the description stay up while the mouse button is held down?

Comment: Edited. Descrption should stay until i click again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/2gyg5m85/1/

you can use a `input`(checkbox) to find `:checked` or unchecked state to trigger show hide you can `position` the `input` is over the `div` on which you want to click

```css
div + input:checked ~ div {
  display: none;
}
input {
  width: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="trigger">Title</div>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <div>description</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible using the :active selector. But it is very limited to what u can perform and its not supported across all browsers.

```css
.description{
 display: none;
}
.title:active + .description{
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="title">Title</div>
 <div class="description">description</div>
</body>
```

Comment: With this method the description does not stay visible after you click on it.

Comment: True but the OP hasn't defined what they mean by 'click'. the whole question is too broad in my opinion. There are multiple solutions including a 'checkbox-hack` as well as this, and yours.

Comment: That's what i meant when i said "it is very limited". A pure CSS solution is not possible to make the description stay visible after you click on title once

Comment: Actually, it possible to fake a "permanent" click (using `:active`) with a long transition - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ztoGJ

Comment: @Paulie_D: Yeah.. true.. But transitions dont work for "display" property though

Comment: True...but then I'd substitute this - http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=337. Still the best way is JS, of course.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using the pseudo-class `:focus`.  For elements that can not be focused you have to add `tabindex`

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/93p4x1u4/)

**Example**

```
<div tabindex="0" class="title">Title</div>
<div class="desc">description</div>

.desc {
  display: none;
}

.title:focus ~ .desc {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give id to the div and handle the event.

```
<div id="title">Title</div>
<div id="description">description</div>

$(document).on("click","#title",function(){

    $("#desc").toggle();

})
```

Without Javascript you can use active or hover

```
#description{
    display: none;
}
#title:hover + #description{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: The op asked if this was possible without javascript

Comment: Yes we can do using hover and active properties. Can you tell me full form of OP

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you want to use a framework that has this already included, like:

- Bootstrap

  http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse
- jQuery

  http://webcloud.se/jQuery-Collapse/

Good luck